# WCF 405 webmethod not found issue

Tags: wcf, web-services, http-status-code-405

I have a requirement of creating a webservice where the client and the service will talk in Simple Soap (that request and response will be soap), I tried all to find a sample example on net where this thing is already done or some code sample so that I can get started but I think I am bad in searching google, that is why can't find any one so far, Some one suggested to use WCF so get an article

http://csharping.com/wcf/building-a-soap-response-envelope-manually-with-the-message-class/

But again my problem is not solved, I tried to create an application with this sample (with so many issues :( )

Created a console application and the Program.cs is

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;


namespace ServiceConsole
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(ServiceClient), new Uri("http://localhost:2000/")))
            {
                ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint = new ServiceEndpoint(
                    ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(IService)));               

                ServiceEndpoint metadataEndpoint = new ServiceEndpoint(
                    ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(IMetadataExchange)));               

                ServiceMetadataBehavior metadataBehavior = serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
                if (metadataBehavior == null)
                {
                    metadataBehavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                    metadataBehavior.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                    serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(metadataBehavior);
                }


                serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), new BasicHttpBinding(), "http://localhost:2000/");
                serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(), "http://localhost:2000/WCFService/mex");
                serviceHost.Open();

                string requestData = "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><s:Header><h:HeaderItem xmlns:h=\"http://tempuri.org/\">a header item</h:HeaderItem><ActivityId CorrelationId=\"090c553b-bfcc-4e4f-94cd-1b4333fe82a9\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics\">377a454b-b543-4c6f-b4ac-3981029b60e6</ActivityId></s:Header><s:Body><string xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/\">a body item</string></s:Body></s:Envelope>";
                byte[] requestDataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestData);

                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/WCFService/");
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
                request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/IWebService/GetMessage");
                request.ContentLength = requestDataBytes.Length;

                StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
                streamWriter.Write(requestData);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                string responseBody = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

                Console.WriteLine("Service returned the following response...");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
                Console.ReadKey();
                serviceHost.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the `app.config` which I generated using svcutil.exe is like this

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <configuration>
          <system.serviceModel>
            <bindings>
              <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                  <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                      maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                  <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                  </security>
                </binding>
              </basicHttpBinding>
            </bindings>
            <client>
              <endpoint address="http://localhost:2000/WebService/Service.svc"
                  binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
                  contract="IService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
            </client>
          </system.serviceModel>
        </configuration>
```

My webservioce is like (it is a WCF website in which the port is provided by me and is 2000

Service contract is

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Message GetMessage(Message s);
}

[ServiceBehavior]
public class Service : IService
{
    public Message GetMessage(Message message)
    {
        string body = message.GetBody<string>();
        return Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.Soap11, "http://tempuri.org/IWebService/GetMessageResponse", "body is " + body);
    }
```

}

and the `web.config` is

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="Service">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:2000/WebService/Service.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="IService" >
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <timeouts closeTimeout="00:01:10" />
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" policyVersion="Policy15" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

My issue is 405 webmethod not body can anyone please tell me what is an issue in this, I am new to WCF before this created a sample and this is my second application

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create the SOAP message manually, just use basic http binding and that will rturn SOAP.

Comment: Any example where i can test it, please and what about client request, thanks for response

Answer (score 0):

When you have a WCF service, the whole point is that you can define e.g. parameters like strings, int and so forth - and you don't have to mess with loads of XML and SOAP headers and bodies.

So basically, your service contract should be something like:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    int DoSomeMathAddTowNumbers(int num1, int num2);
}
```

and your service implementation would then just implement that method, add the two numbers, and return the result:

```
public class Service : IService
{
    int DoSomeMathAddTowNumbers(int num1, int num2)
    {
         return num1 + num2;  
    }
}
```

No mess with `Message` or XML manipulation or anything.

A client that wants to call your service would create a WCF client-side proxy using `svcutil` or the Visual Studio `Add Service Reference` method, and it would get a proxy class that has the same methods as the service it connects to - and you would call them, using the straight, easy parameters - something like:

```
ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
int result = client.DoSomeMathAddTwoNumbers(42, 100);
```

So basically, I think you need to get back to the drawing board and read up on the WCF basics again - it should **not** be that difficult, really! (that's the whole point - it should make services **easy** ...)

Check out the [Beginner's Guide at the WCF Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd939784) at MSDN - it contains lots of really good videos, screencasts, articles on how to get started with WCF.-

You might also want to check out the DotNet Rocks TV episode #135: [Keith Elder Demystifies WCF](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=135)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, creating such a thing won't be difficult and there are hundred of samples available, but requirement is pass saop message not int or double pass soap and get soap , i will check this video also , thanks for the link and reply

Comment: WCF service **are** passing SOAP messages! .... but you don't have to manually assemble those messages yourself - the WCF runtime will do this for you under the covers....

Comment: what if we have to do it can we do it or not

Comment: Actually I don't know what is the client that will consume my webservice sorry my apologizes I forgot the important part of my question ...

Comment: @Sharee: doesn't matter - as long as the client can talk SOAP, your WCF service will work just fine - using `int` and `string` parameters and all that goodness... really: **there's no need to manually construct SOAP messages** on the client, and there's no need to deal with raw SOAP messages on the server, either!

Comment: hmm , requirement  is requirement and tehre was a big reason to do this and I handled this by using message object in WCF .. thanks to every one for taking time to reply my question...